# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into List<> 'because the type requires a JSON object "

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dotnet-httpclient

I am getting the

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Mercury.TGC.Service.DTO.ContactResponseDto' because the type requires
>   a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

What am I doing wrong?

Json returned from API

```
{
"status": "Success",
"body": {
"companyName": "keep org merge test",
"taxId": "tax id2",
"addresses": [
{
"id": 100,
"addressName": "Location 1",
"address1": "1234 Create Ave",
"address2": "Suite 1234",
"city": "West Des Moines",
"state": "IA",
"postalCode": "50266",
"country": "USA",
"latitude": 41.575011,
"longitude": 93.709212,
"isPrimary": true,
"imageShortkey": "5a0lc9ge5n",
"types": [],
"phones": []
}
],
"phones": [
{
"id": 122,
"phoneNumber": "515-924-2452",
"phoneType": "Work",
"isPrimary": true,
"extension": null
},
{
"id": 123,
"phoneNumber": "515-326-1919",
"phoneType": "Work",
"isPrimary": false,
"extension": null
}
],
"id": 5100,
"searchOptOut": false,
"tradeCodes": [],
"doingBusinessAs": [],
"leedLevel": 3,
"hasBimExperience": true,
"facebookURL": null,
"twitterHandle": null,
"yearFounded": "1924",
"profileText": null,
"mainEmail": null,
"websiteURL": null,
"logoURL": null,
"currentEmr": 1.2
},
"messages": null
}
```

C# code:

```
class RestfulResponseContactDto {
    public string Status {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ContactResponseDto Body {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List<string> Messages {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ContactResponseDto {        
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } 
}

 public class Contact {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string OrgId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get;set; }
    public string LastName { get;set; }
    public string Email { get;set; }
     public string Title { get;set; }
    // public List<addresses> addresses { get; set; }
    //public List<phones> phones { get; set; } 
    //public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
    //public string RequestStatus { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: how are you `deserializing`?

Comment: I recommend you compare your objects with those generated from [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) to determine validity.

Comment: in the first "phones" you have a "{" missing so this is not valid json

Comment: The last line of code does the deserializing

Comment: It is a valid JSON, I just validated it using http://jsonlint.com/....

Comment: @EBrown: I generated classes from the site you suggested and used those instead of my original.  No luck..same error

Comment: I didn't say to use those *specifically.* That site is never 100% accurate on complex object-types such as this, I merely mentioned it as a starting base for you to get a good foundation of what the code should expect. Without actual `deserialization` code we cannot assist you to much an extent except to say *verify your classes match your JSON.* Alternatively, you could `deserialize` it to a `dynamic` object and explore it.